# How to create links in html same as Linkbutton as in a Repeater in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, command-line-arguments

I have a project that list many questions from database .This questions ask to people and get votes from them. when I select any question it needs to display their votes on chart and its votes.I do not Want  to use repeater .how can I get the ID of Question from list .In Repeater I use commandArgument but in my strategy this is not allowed by using system .I need to use any links for call something by commandargument like Using linkbutton in repeater functionality .How can I do that. Please help me.

If I use repeater I can get ID of question like this :

```
int ID = General.StrtoInt(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

and When I use repeater I use like this :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RptRecord" OnItemDataBound="RptRecord_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="RptRecord_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr class="odd gradeX">
                    <td class="hidden-phone" style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:Literal ID="LblSiraNo" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="hidden-phone" style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:Literal ID="LblSoru" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="hidden-phone" style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ChckIsVisible" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="hidden-phone" style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkBtnIstatistik" runat="server" class="btn blue mini" CommandName="CmdName_Istatistik"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkBtnGuncelle" runat="server" class="btn green mini" CommandName="CmdName_Guncelle" Visible="false" OnClientClick="showPopup()"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkBtnSil" runat="server" class="btn red mini" CommandName="CmdName_Sil" Visible="false" OnClientClick="if(uyar()) showPopup();"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <tr class="odd gradeX" style="background-color: bisque">
                    <td class="hidden-phone" style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:Literal ID="LblSiraNo" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="hidden-phone" style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:Literal ID="LblSoru" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="hidden-phone" style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ChckIsVisible" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="hidden-phone" style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkBtnIstatistik" runat="server" class="btn blue mini" CommandName="CmdName_Istatistik"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkBtnGuncelle" runat="server" class="btn green mini" CommandName="CmdName_Guncelle" Visible="false" OnClientClick="showPopup()"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkBtnSil" runat="server" class="btn red mini" CommandName="CmdName_Sil" Visible="false" OnClientClick="if(uyar()) showPopup();"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the asp.net code with using html:

```
string a1 = "", a2 = "", a3 = "", a4 = "", a5 = "";
   foreach (var item in lst_cevap1)
    {
       BirimVO brm = birimBUS.Birim(item.PoliklinikID);


       str += "     <div class=\"portlet-body\">";
      // bu kısım tablonun body kısmının head kısmı


  str += "<table class=\"table table-striped table-bordered table-advance table-hover\">               ";
  str += "<thead>                                                                                ";
  str += "  <tr>                                                                               ";
  str += "  <th>" + GetContent.Cevir((int)eCeviri.Sıra_No) + "</th>                                   ";
  str += "  <th> "+birimAdi + "</th>                                   ";
  str += "  <th>" + Cevap1 + "</th>    ";
  str += "  <th>" + Cevap2 + "</th>    ";
  str += "  <th>" + Cevap3 + "</th>    ";
  str += "  <th>" + Cevap4 + "</th>    ";
  str += "  <th>" + Cevap5 + "</th>    ";
  str += "  <th>" + GetContent.Cevir((int)eCeviri.Toplam) + "</th>                                   ";
  str += " <th> Chart Göster                                </th>                                   ";
  str += "                  </tr>                                                                              ";
   str += "             </thead>                                                                               ";
   str += "             <tbody>                                                                                ";

   sira++;
   str += "                 <tr>                                                                               ";
   str += "                     <td>" + sira.ToString() + "</td>                                             ";
   str += "                     <td>";


    str += questionV1.Text;
                                    if (Cevap3 !="")
                                    {
                                        a3 = item.iyisayisi.ToString();
                                    }
                                    if (Cevap4 != "")
                                    {
                                        a4 = item.ortasayisi.ToString();
                                    }
                                    if (Cevap5 != "")
                                    {
                                        a5 = item.kotusayisi.ToString();
                                    }
                                    str += "</td>                  ";
                                    str += "                        <td>" + item.cevap1sayisi + "</td>                                             ";
                                    str += "                        <td>" + item.cevap1sayisi + "</td>                                             ";
                                    str += "                        <td>" + a3 + "</td>                                             ";
                                    str += "                        <td>" + a4 + "</td>                         ";
                                    str += "                        <td>" + a5+ "</td>    ";
                                    str += "                        <td>" + item.toplam + "</td>                    ";
                                    str += "                        <td>"+BirimID+","+questionV1.ID+"</td>                           ";
                                    str += "                    </tr>                                                                              ";
                                }
                                #endregion
```

Comment: `I do not Want to use repeater .how can I get the ID of Question from list .In Repeater I use commandArgument but in my strategy this is not allowed by using system ` explain please!

Comment: when I use repeater I can get The ID of question from table . Bu my  new sistem not allow repeater  so I need to list question and in list I use linkbutton or another method .Using this method qive me the ID of question to use for getting votes of  question from database.

Comment: okay, use listview instead repeater

Comment: I will try to use this method.

Comment: Is there  any  different method instead of using listview because I could not  use it.

Comment: haha what you can use?

Comment: your method is like repeater . I do not want to use this method because I use html with csharp code  not use automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your questions from the database. Loop over the questions, and create the controls you need manually, manually assigning unique IDs, combining a name and the database ID, like `lblQuestion101`.

Comment: I tried but how can I use as a link. My aim click any question , the click give me display something by using questionID.

Comment: You could use the QueryString to deliver the ID to the next Page.